# Match only if not preceded or followed by a digit

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression to look for phone numbers in a codebase:

```
\\d{3}[\.\s-]?\d{3}[\.\s-]?\d{4}\g
```

How can I modify this so that it *will not* match instances where the number is preceded or followed by a digit?

```
18005555555 (should not match)
80055555551 (should not match)
"8005555555" (should match)
s800-555-5555 (should match)
8005555555 (should match)
800.555.5555 (should match)
```

**Edit**:
I'm not trying to "match the whole word", because it is not sufficient that the match is preceded by and followed by a space. See the 3rd example of above that should also return a match.

I want to match only instances where the match is not preceded or followed by *a digit*.

In others words:

```
[NOT DIGIT][PHONE NUMBER][NOT DIGIT]
```

Comment: Enclose with `^` and `$`? [`/^\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{4}$/`](https://regex101.com/r/oI4dT9/3)

Comment: or use word-boundries `\b` if it is contained in text

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that solution would not match "s8005555555" when it should.

Comment: @SebastianProske, I want to also match those instances where a letter or another character may come before or after the numbers.

Comment: @Himmel - so using lookahead and lookbehind should work, try `(?<!\d)\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{4}(?!\d)`

Comment: If it is JS flavor: [`/(^|\D)(\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{4})(?!\d)/`](https://regex101.com/r/oI4dT9/5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookahead and lookbehind will help you with these restrictions - if they are supported, like

```
/(?<!\d)\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{3}[.\s-]?\d{4}(?!\d)/g
```

You can replace the lookbehind `(?<!\d)` with `(?:^|\D)` if it is not supported. You can replace the lookahead `(?!\d)` with `(?:\D|$)` if it is not supported.

You can find a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/aS8jQ8/1